# About the foundations of category theory

Tags: ct.category-theory

Is there a known way to built category theory on sound foundation, as occurs with axiomatic set theory ?

As far as I know, there exists at least to ways to talk about category theory :

1. To consider each Hom(X,Y) as an element of ZFC. Does this lead to some paradoxes ?
2. To avoid the use of ZFC. Can that be done in a rigourous manner ?

I know that there has been a debate about these foundation issues in the 60's and 70's among mathematicians (small categories vs big categories, use by Grothendieck of the notion of "universes" to link properly set theory to  category theory, work of Benabou on the foundations of category theory...) , but is this debate closed today ?

Can you recommend some recent bibliography on that matter ?

Comment: See my answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9269/category-of-categories-as-a-foundation-of-mathematics

Comment: Regarding your 1: first of all, when you say "an element of ZFC," presumably you mean "an element of a model of ZFC." More seriously, categories where the $\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ form sets are called "locally small" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)#Small_and_large_categories) and often one wants to consider bigger categories than this.

Comment: @Sam Hopkins : can you give me examples of categories in which Hom(X,Y) cannot be considered as a set ?

Comment: @huurd: see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3278/whats-a-reasonable-category-that-is-not-locally-small

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are grothendieck universes enough for the foundations of category theory?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115099/are-grothendieck-universes-enough-for-the-foundations-of-category-theory)

Answer (score 9):

Mike Shulman wrote an [excellent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279) addressing various set-theoretical foundations for category theory and their consequences for the behavior of ${\bf Set}$; a brief summary can be found in my [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383779/when-the-definition-of-a-set-starts-to-matter-in-category-theory/383883#383883) to another MO question, but I highly recommend checking out Mike's paper firsthand.